# Export only part of a project into .dae?

Tags: export, collada

When I simply go to `File` > `Export` > `Collada (Default) (dae)` then the whole project is exported as a single .dae file, telling me helpfully that they exported all the objects:

[image]

Blender doesn't care if an item is visible, or selected. it exports everything. The only workaround I found on my own was to save the file (exporting seems to at times crash), then delete all but the part I wish to export, then revert the deletion. But that appears tedious.

Is there a way to only export a single object and not everything in a blender file?

Comment: In pretty much all exporters there is a setting in the export window to include only the selection

Comment: The selected dupe wasn't really findable for me, and is about stl but good.